# c#. array keeps resetting itself in my switch

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement

I'm currently in programming 101 and I've been stuck for a long time with an issue.

My assignment wants me to create a class with a bunch of methods to run with a switch case( as a menu).

If I press 1 (add passenger), it does what it's supposed to do the first time, but the second time, it just restarts the array.

I can't seem to save my answer to the array and then move on to the next spot in the array.

Would someone please explain how I'm supposed to "call" the array and save in it outside my for-loop in method `add_pass`?

```
using System;

namespace bussen
{
    class buss
    {
        public int[] passagerare;
        public int numbof_passagerare;
        
        public void Run()
        {
            int nmr = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("options:");
                Console.WriteLine("1 add passenger");
                Console.WriteLine("2 print out all passengers");
                Console.WriteLine("3 calc average age");
                Console.WriteLine("0 close program");
                nmr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());      

                switch (nmr)
                {
                    case 1:add_pass();
                        break;

                    case 2:all_pass();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        break;

                    case 0:
                        break;
                }
            } while (nmr != 0);
        }

        public void add_pass()
        {
            if (passagerare.Length < 5)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("type age of passenger");
                    int numbof_passenger = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    passagerare[i] = numbof_passenger;
                    break;
                }
            }       
            else if(passagerare.Length >= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("buss is full");
            }
        }

        public void all_pass()
        {
            foreach(int index in passagerare)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(index);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var minbuss = new buss();
            minbuss.Run();
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change public int[] passagerare; to  public int[] passagerare = new int[5];

Comment: You'd be better with a list rather than an array, them you can just add to it easily without worrying

Comment: This site is not about doing your homework. That said the community is happy to help. What does 'restarts the array' mean? What exactly is the output? What exactly do you expect/want for output?

Comment: @Sergey That won't help much since the loop inside `add_pass()` will always overwrite the first element.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: ADyson, we're meant to only use array and not list for this assignment.

Comment: `(passagerare.Length < 5)' should most likely be '( numbof_passenger< 5)`.  `passagerare[i] = numbof_passenger;` should most likely be `passagerare[inumbof_passenger++];`  and the `add_pass()` method should not have a loop as this always breaks;

Comment: A huge thanks to all of you for support. so the problem was that every time i pressed 1 in the switch menu it added a passenger to the first place in array [] passagerare. i could never save  "that seat in the buss" and move on to the next.

Comment: @tobleroo if you found your own solution, you should add it to the Answers, below. That way, people can vote on it if they find it useful in future, in a similar situation. You are allowed to answer your own question. Putting the solution in the comments isn't helpful - it's not searchable and the code isn't very readable. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you aren't sure how StackOverflow's question and answer system works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's starting over because you're telling it to start over. The for loop starts at 0 every time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("type age of passenger");
    int numbof_passenger = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    passagerare[i] = numbof_passenger;
    break;
}
```

You need to find the length of the array and append the new entry. Try using a List instead of any array.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was within the add_pass method, where i used a for - loop to add passengers. each time i pressed number 1 in the menu to call the method , the loop restarted the array wich i was saving the integers to.To get this right i just called the method without a loop like shown below. Thanks everybody for your help!

```
 public void add_pass()
    {
        if (numbof_passagerare < 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("how old is the passenger");
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            passagerare[numbof_passagerare++] = age;
        }
        else if(numbof_passagerare == 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("buss is full!");
        }
```